# PythonでCSVデータの整理

Tags: python, pandas

初めまして。初心者ですがよろしくお願いします。
図の左のようなCSVファイルを読み込んだとします。
A列は人を表し、B列のa,bは身長、体重を表しています（cは穴埋めなので気にしないでください）。
C列はB列に対応した数値になっています。
同じ人がa,bを不規則に測っている通り、いくつものデータを持っている場合、その人の中の最も新しい数値(ここでは行が下に行くほど新しいデータとなる)のみを取り出して、右の図のようなCSVファイルを作りたいのですが、どのように組めば、うまく動くでしょうか？
説明が上手くできずに申し訳ございません。

追記：　利用者IDは図の列Aに値して、コンテンツIDは列Bに値し、値は列Cに値します。

```
column = data[['利用者ID','コンテンツID','値']]

for i in range(len(column['利用者ID'])):
    if column.iloc[i,1] != 1003 or column.iloc[i,1] != 1004:
        column.drop(i)
```

自分で作ったコードはこれです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 書きかけでも構わないので自分で書いたコードを提示することは出来ませんか？この内容だと「どこで困っているか(他人から)分からない」「代わりにコードを書いてください」になってしまいます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！今手元にないので、コードを提示できないのですが、今やろうとしてるやり方ですと、a,b以外の要素(ここではc)の行を削除して、出来上がったものの、それぞれの人の古い身長体重の行を削除していこうとしています。そこで、現在つまづいているのは、a,b以外の要素の行をfor文で回してifで削除しようとしているのですが、そこのコードがうまくかけてないみたいで、うまく動きません。

Comment: 質問文は後からでも「編集」できますので、コードが手元にある時にぜひ追記をお願いします。

Comment: りょうかいしました。明日の夜までには追記しますので、是非よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 遅れてごめんなさい。コードを載せました。

Answer (score 3):

*回答が付かない上に-1までされていたので、フォローしたいと思います*

ご質問の内容は、つまりこう言うことになります。

> Pandasでデータフレームをグループ化した時、各グループの最後の行を取り出すにはどうしたらいいか？

Pandasのgroupbyは読み込み順を維持します。そして.last()で最後の行を取り出せば目的を達成できると思います。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = '''\
利用者ID,コンテンツID,値
1,a,170
1,b,60
1,c,0
1,a,169
2,c,0
2,a,157
2,b,45
2,a,155
2,b,46
2,c,0
2,a,155
2,b,45
3,c,0
3,a,171
3,b,65
3,a,170
4,c,0
4,a,158
4,b,51
5,a,149
5,a,150
5,b,35
5,c,0
5,b,35
5,a,151
5,c,0
5,b,38
'''

with StringIO(data) as csvfile:
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
    summery = df.groupby(['利用者ID', 'コンテンツID']).last()
    # "c"を除外したければ次の通り
    # summery = df.query('コンテンツID != "c"').groupby(['利用者ID', 'コンテンツID']).last()
print(summery.to_csv())
```

## 実行結果

```
利用者ID,コンテンツID,値
1,a,169
1,b,60
1,c,0
2,a,155
2,b,45
2,c,0
3,a,170
3,b,65
3,c,0
4,a,158
4,b,51
4,c,0
5,a,151
5,b,38
5,c,0
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。今から参考にさせていただいて、やってみます！

Comment: groupbyを参考にコードを作ってみたところ、うまく動かせることができました。丁寧にご回答ありがとうございました。